# How can I setup port forwarding through VPN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding

Let's start from what do I have:

- Mikrotik router with static IP and VPN running on it (L2TP)
- Home PC directly connected to Mikrotik
- MiWifi router with Padavan firmware and without static external IP (connected to Mikrotik through VPN)
- IP-camera with 554 port (connected to MiWifi router)

How can I get access to camera from Home PC?

I forwarded 554 port in router to IP of IP-camera, but on Home PC I see only 22, 80 ports of my MiWifi router. I guess I have wrong VPN settings..

Thanks!

Comment: If the camera has an address accessible through the VPN there is no need to port-forward.

Comment: Agreed with @Tim_Stewart.  If you want to access your camera through VPN, RDP to your home PC, open a browser and type the IP address of your camera.  If you want to access your camera from your phone without VPN'ing into your network, let me know and I'll be happy to give you directions on how to achieve this.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart not direct access, only through router

Comment: @pythonian I don't have camera's IP because it's behind the xiaomi router